# How to Customize Polylang Language Items

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-polylang

I am using Polylang plugin with WordPress 4.3.1, Can you please let me know if there is a way to display language items in short abbriviation like `En` for `English` or `CH` for `Chinese`

I am using this code to display the active languages

```
<?php pll_the_languages();?>
```

and the result looks like

[image]

Can you please let me know how to shorten them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `display_names_as` parameter when calling `pll_the_languages()`. I tried it on an installation with English and French languages and it returned me `en` and `fr` respectively.

```
<?php pll_the_languages( array( 'display_names_as' => 'slug' ) );?>
```

You can find the function reference for the Polylang plugin on [this page](https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/).